# Adding node in XML at specified location in c#

Tags: c#, xml

This is what my xml looks like:

```
<Runners>
<Runner>
    <RunnersBadge>
    123
    </RunnersBadge>
    <Times>
    </Times>
</Runner>

<Runner>
    <RunnersBadge>
    456
    </RunnersBadge>
    <Times>
    </Times>
</Runner>
```

I can find the specific runner, for example 123 with this code:

```
//loadxml
string findrunner = "123";
XmlNodelist nodelist = "xmldocument".SelectNodes("Runners\Runner")

foreach(XmlNode node in nodelist)
{
 if ( node["RunnersBadge"].InnerText.Equals(findrunner)
{
 //This is how far I get, I can find the runner because if I put a value inside times
 //and output it in a message box, it is showing the proper one for runner 123.
}
```

How would I go about adding a node inside  called  so the xml looks like this:

```
<Runners>
<Runner>
    <RunnersBadge>
    123
    </RunnersBadge>
    <Times>
        <LapTime>
        </LapTime>
        <LapTime>
        </LapTime>
    </Times>
</Runner>

<Runner>
    <RunnersBadge>
    456
    </RunnersBadge>
    <Times>
    </Times>
</Runner>
```

I can add  inside  using CreateElement("LapTime") then ApphendChild and then saving it.  That just creates the new node/element inside , how would I go about going one more level so I can add the new node/element inside ?

Comment: Are you asking how to add the `LapTime` nodes as children of the `Times` node instead of the `Runner` node?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I've been at it a few hours and no luck.

Comment: You just need to select the `Times` node instead of `Runner` node before you call `AppendChild`. You have the `Runner` node in your loop, grab the child named `Times`, and call `AppendChild` on that node.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should add the new node up to two levels as required...

```
string message = "<Insert XML Here>";
string findrunner = "123";
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(message);
XmlNodeList nodelist = document.SelectNodes("//Runner");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
{
    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (child.Name == "RunnersBadge" && child.InnerText.Equals(findrunner))
        {
            XmlNode Times = null;
            XmlNode LapTime = null;
            if ((Times = node.SelectSingleNode("//Times")) == null)
            {
                Times = document.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Times", "");
                node.AppendChild(Times);
            }

            LapTime = document.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "LapTime", "");
            LapTime.InnerText = ""; // Set Value Here
            Times.AppendChild(LapTime);
            break;
        }     
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, this one sort of works, but it keeps putting the new node on the first runners Times no matter which RunnerBadge I try.  I tried linq to xml and it did the opposite, puts it on the last runner everytime :/